How can I fix the lengths of all the plotted lines to be the same when plotting one-forms?
I am preparing tutorials for physics students on vectors and one-forms. The latter are basically contour lines and I can generate the graphs with no problem. What I need to do is fix the lengths of all the plotted contours lines to be the same length (preferably specified by me somehow).
Here is my MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    view={0}{90},
    %grid  = major,
    xtick = {-4,-3,...,4},
    xmin  = -4.1,
    xmax  =  4.1,
    ytick = {-4,-3,...,4},
    ymin  = -4.1,
    ymax  =  4.1,
  ]
\addplot3 [%
    very thick,
    contour lua = {%
        % levels sets how many lines are drawn, one for each value
        %levels  = {-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
        levels  = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
        labels  = false,  % shows orientation (direction is from - to +)
        draw color = red, % for testing purposes
    },
    samples = 10,
    domain  = -2:2, % this can vary the lengths of the red lines
  ] {(2*x + 2*y)};  % vary the coefficients to get different 1-forms
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here is the output. Notice how the one-form "fills the space" so to speak.

Here is what I would like to achieve. All the red lines have the same length regardless of the one-form's orientation and I would like to be able to specify and vary that length somehow. I created this by hand using a laptop trackpad so the lines' lengths are not precisely all the same. Another way of saying it is that the red lines should fit into a rectangle, be parallel to two opposite sides and perpendicular to the other two sides.


No idea what a one-form is or why you want to modify the display, but you can always add a clipping box.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    view={0}{90},
    %grid  = major,
    xtick = {-4,-3,...,4},
    xmin  = -4.1,
    xmax  =  4.1,
    ytick = {-4,-3,...,4},
    ymin  = -4.1,
    ymax  =  4.1,
  ]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2,0) -- (2,4) -- (2,0) -- (-2,-4) -- cycle;
\addplot3 [%
    very thick,
    contour lua = {%
        % levels sets how many lines are drawn, one for each value
        %levels  = {-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
        levels  = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
        labels  = false,  % shows orientation (direction is from - to +)
        draw color = red, % for testing purposes
    },
    samples = 50,
    domain  = -2:2, % this can vary the lengths of the red lines
  ] {(2*x + 2*y)};  % vary the coefficients to get different 1-forms
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


One-forms are mathematical objects used in differential geometry and relativity theory (other places too). I felt sure there was probably a simple way to do this that I was missing and using \clip seems to do the trick. Will wait a bit longer before accepting just to make sure.
